# using reboot.css and styling h1 in my pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and `reboot.css` looks like to applying default stylinng to html elements. I am applying style to h1 via `.h1` but that is can't override the style of reboot.css. I don't want to use `!improtant`. What will be the standard way to override styles in reboot.css?

Comment: Just load your styles after `reboot.css`. They will have higher importance by default. Take a look at [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) too.

Comment: okay... That made me feel stupid...

Comment: sometimes the simple things are right in front of our face.

Comment: @Alex I think this will be an answer.

Comment: kham, created an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your styles after the `reboot.css`, this way they will have higher importance.

Also have a read about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) too.